# Xamarin.Andriod: How to Receive message and show Notification

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I would like to show a notification when Received SMS... but can't do it because I can't change to static 'StartService(intente);'
what should I change in my code?

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.HasExtra("pdus"))
    {
        var smsArray = (Java.Lang.Object[])intent.Extras.Get("pdus");
        string address = "";
        string message = "";
        foreach (var item in smsArray)
        {
            var sms = SmsMessage.CreateFromPdu((byte[])item);
            _message = sms.MessageBody;
            _sender = sms.OriginatingAddress;
        }
        if (_sender.Contains(txtCarNumber.Text.Substring(1, 10)))
        {
            MsgReceived(_message, context);
            SwitchClass.StopProgress();
            // For Show on Notification
            var intente = new Intent(context, typeof(NotificationsCommand));
            intente.PutExtra("Command", "TurnOff");
            StartService(intente); //=> here compiler say should be Static
                                   // End
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with :

```
context.StartService(intente);
```

Here is a [discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/122868/broadcastreceiver-cant-start-service-on-boot-reboot) for reference.

Comment: @RasoolAghajani Glad works ! Thanks for replying and marking. *.^